# JSF ajax keyup render inpuText does not work

Tags: html, ajax, jsf, jsf-2

my jsf page looks like this:

```
<p:inputText value="#{bean.name}" required="true" styleClass="#{component.valid ? 'ui-input-valid' : 'ui-input-invalid'}">
    <f:ajax event="keyup" render="@this" /> 
</p:inputText>
```

The Web App should be change styleClass when ONE letter is in the inputText. But when i am typing into the inputText the rendering does not work really. Because the rendering is to slow.
Is another way possible?

Best regards
Hege088

Comment: Can you describe what you actually want to happen? You've not attached /shown any validators, so the component will always be valid and re-rendering is pointless. In any case, perform validation that needs instant response on the client.

Comment: When component.valid is modified? <f:ajax> doesn't contains any actionlistener.